# How to extract only selected component-related source from library?

Tags: delphi, components

What techniques exist to extract only a selected component's source from the library in which it was packaged in? The intent is to isolate the component's source for installation as a separate component, thus avoiding installation of the entire library.

For example:
I have the complete TMS VCL library with source code, and I only need the TAdvDBDateTimePicker. How can I extract the required (referenced) Delphi sources needed only to install this component.?

Is there any existing tool to accomplish this task? Would ModelMaker Code Explorer have a feature to accomplish this?

TIA.

Comment: This is a common term "Reverse Engineering" on a trial/error basis. Start with identifying which units are being used. Then, identify what is within those units that are needed. Create your own new unit, and start copying those findings, and look for the missing pieces, copying them as you find them. However, be aware of copyright infringement.

Comment: Or, the easier way is make a complete copy of those units, start removing chunks that don't look relevant and see if something breaks.

Comment: You can copy and paste a class with MMX and it will fill in the uses clauses needed for that class. If you did this to a new project then it should tell you what you need from a classes point of view. You could also use ModelMaker (not MMX) to drag the class onto a layout. Then there is an option to put all of the dependencies for that class on the layout. Rinse and repeating should help to give you a good map of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What work has done is to sub-class the component(s) and only install the sub-classed components. Using your example, you install the TMS components but remove them from the IDE's palette. You then create a sub-class of the required components pointing to the source of the original components:

```
type
  TSteveTMSAdvDBDateTimePicker = class(TAdvDBDateTimePicker);
```

No reverse engineering required, very doubtful if there is any copyright infringement (assuming you aren't distributing these components and only being used by people that have purchased TMS components).

Comment: I want to distribute the component that is extracted to someone who doesn't have the entire library installed. Thanks for the suggestion though. I see the point about copyright infringement.